# Serving php through IIS instead of Plesk

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, plesk

I have IIS 7 and Plesk 10.4.4 on my Cloud Server. I need to update php version. Right now php is being served by Plesk, and I don't know how to update it with Plesk.

I've managed to install the latest version with IIS 7 and Php Manager, so I was wondering, how can I force php serving through IIS instead of Plesk? Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP it's just binary file you can take necessary complied files and just replace it where it installed in plesk %plesk_dir%\Additional\pleskphp5, but you have to create backup of replaced files and preserve all current permissions.

There possible issues with future upgrade to next plesk version, because files replacement can make Windows Installer crazy.

Btw Plesk 11.5 has feature which allows to add your own PHP handlers.

Comment: Thanks, I updated to 11.5 and enabled php 5.4. Not the latest version but it's working.
I'd rather not substitute files by hand, just for the reasons you described. Still I would like to know how to use IIS to manage php.

Comment: Ok, I've found the option in IIS, now I can handle it as I prefer.